# Identify TNEF attachment in MailBee

Tags: email, tnef

Q: I am using MailBee to gets attachemnt in winmail.data(TNEF), but I am got several other files which content type is application/octet-stream, I don't want to save this type as attachment.

Currently, my solution is using content type to judge it.

```
if (tnefAttachment.ContentType.ToLower() != "application/octet-stream")
{
    SaveAttachment(tnefAttachment); 
}
```

I don't want using content type to identify it, so have any other solution workable?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of files within TNEF are you interested in? Embedded pictures, maybe?

Comment: As usual, the email contains the attachment such as Word(.docx) or Excel(.xlsx) file etc, which are encode as TNEF format, so when I am use MailBee to decode the TNEF data, I got several files which extension name is like 'application/octet-stream', and only 1 .doc file in the attachments, which is I want to saved one.

Comment: It's pretty arbitrary choice of preferences of "what to save and what to skip". You need some strict, well-defined rule to determine what you want to save and what not. Currently it looks like "there are some files I want to save and there are others". BTW, application/octet-stream is universal content-type, a document file can have it sometimes. For instance, you can tell us "I want to save all files with .doc, .docx, .xls or .xlsx extension and ignore everything else. How to achieve?", etc.

Comment: All right, so I need a white list rule to filter the attachments. Thanks for you help.